# Inappbilling add item and save it

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to add InAppBilling funciton to my android application. I just like to know before I do my alfa test that is it enough if I add the item (which is an int variable) with SharedPreferences and save it with SharedPreferences on this way:

```
private static final String HINT = "Hint";
private static final String VALUE = "VALUE";
int hints;

private static final String TAG =
        "com.example.game";
com.example.game.util.IabHelper mHelper;
static final String ITEM_SKU = "com.lots.hints";

private Button clickButton;
private Button buyButton;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pontpiac);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_pontpiac);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.hide();


    SharedPreferences sphint = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    hints = sphint.getInt(VALUE, 0);

    buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buyButton);
   clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "<my base64 code>";

    mHelper = new com.example.game.util.IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               com.example.game.util.IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(com.example.game.util.IabResult result) {
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                   result);
                                       } else {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                       }
                                   }
                               });
}

public void buttonClicked (View view)
{
    clickButton.setEnabled(false);
    buyButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public void buyClick(View view) {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}


com.example.game.util.IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new com.example.game.util.IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(com.example.game.util.IabResult result,
                                      com.example.game.util.Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
            consumeItem();
            buyButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
};

public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

com.example.game.util.IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new com.example.game.util.IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(com.example.game.util.IabResult result,
                                         com.example.game.util.Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

com.example.game.util.IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new com.example.game.util.IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(com.example.game.util.Purchase purchase,
                                          com.example.game.util.IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {

                    hints = hints + 50;

                    clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
                Toast.makeText(Pontpiac.this, "You have "+hints + " piece of hints!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}

public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey,
                                     String signedData, String signature) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(signedData) ||
            TextUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey) ||
            TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    PublicKey key = com.example.game.util.Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);
    return com.example.game.util.Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor et = sp.edit();
    et.putInt(VALUE, hints);
    et.commit();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(HINT, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor et = sp.edit();
    et.putInt(VALUE, hints);
    et.commit();
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

I'm just confused and don't know where to add the item. Only in the IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener method? 
If anyone know that please response!